# Prophet Quest - Dragon Bridge

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

As part of the "Prophet" quest:

> you are asked to visit Dragon Bridge to ask about a Moth Priest. Several of the NPCs have conversation options where they advise you to "speak to one of the guards".

There are 2 or 3 guards in Dragon Bridge (Stormcloak soldiers in my case) - but one is dead, having died in a battle with members of the Dawnguard. If I walk past this dead guard, away from the town - the "target" marker appears on my display at the top - indicating that the goal is visible - if I move back towards Dragon Bridge and the dead guard, it disappears.

I think the dead guard is the only one able to tell me the info.

Any way I can recycle this? Will the guard get refreshed after a period of time? I can't continue with the quest as no other NPC in the entire place has any info

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to go just outside Dragon Bridge (Over the actual bridge with the dragon's head on). You will find a dead vampire next to an overturned carriage. Take his note and read.

Comment: Thanks - this worked and advanced the quest so I could carry on. Cheers!